# Android ML-kit chaing together multiple tasks

Tags: android, google-mlkit

I'm trying to run multiple processes using the ml-kit, I've already searched up and the only solutions I've found was to either do all the tasks in succession (how?) or using RXJava and the zip utility but that doesn't seem to match what I need.

I've tried writing the following code but i'm unsure to how good it is, would this be a good way of doing it?

```kotlin
override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
    val inputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image.image!!, image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
    val tasks = mutableListOf<Task<*>>()
    val onComplete = { t: Task<*> ->
        tasks.remove(t)

        if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
            image.close()
        }
    }

    barcodeScanner?.process(inputImage)
        ?.addOnSuccessListener {
            // Do stuff with the result
        }
        ?.addOnCompleteListener(onComplete)
        ?.also {
            tasks.add(it)
        }
    imageLabeler?.process(inputImage)
        ?.addOnSuccessListener {
            // Do stuff with the result
        }
        ?.addOnCompleteListener(onComplete)
        ?.also {
            tasks.add(it)
        }
    faceDetector?.process(inputImage)
        ?.addOnSuccessListener {
            // Do stuff with the result
        }
        ?.addOnCompleteListener(onComplete)
        ?.also {
            tasks.add(it)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You current way will make different inference task queue up in *one* background thread. If you want multi-threading, you can use XxxOptions.Builder #setExecutor to assign detectors different thread.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/barcode/BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder#setExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)

Comment: Can you give more details? How would I use the image from the analyze callback inside the executor?